# Why use async database connection?

Tags: database, asynchronous, asyncpg

I just wonder, why would be the case of using async DB connect.
From my perspective, it's better to tweak query and schema, maybe re-think your indices at first glance.

1. In my understanding, db should be executing no more than a couple of ms.
2. Problem with long connectivity could be solved with connection pulling (constant pinging if there is a tunnel)
3. If you    have async parts of your code, all the code should be async too.

   3.1 Not to forget async is less robust, more error-prone if you have minor experience with it.

   3.2 Async code is longer in a single execution by default, due to the loop nature.

Any really long computation, with the ability to process long networking in business logic - better be done in old fashion - by the separate queue. Since you will lose control of the execution time of your requests anyway. So what is the point anyway?

I could be missing something, but.

As far as I know, Tornado creator (@bdarnell) always saying the same. Correct me please if I'm wrong.

Comment: I do not personally understand your question - if you are using a nodejs run-time environment, you use an async request to the db because it is an I/O operation. By using async, you do not block the main thread so other requests can be executed while your db return a response. If you have long requests, you need to look into the architecture of the app. CPU intensive tasks are not for nodejs.

Comment: That's exactly what I mean. But it's the language-agnostic question. I'm not node user. So many other languages aren't async by default (such as python, c#, ...). As you may expect, writing async code as a bit different from a sync one. So "why" would you chose async db driver.